# How to handle the iframe, passing data from an object inside a for loop

Tags: cypress, cypress-iframe

I'm trying to type a value in an iframe, and the value I'm trying to input is stored in an object that I created. When cypress attempt to type the value, I encounter an error that says **it can only accept a string or number. You passed in: undefined.** However, when I print the object, I can see that there is data retrieved

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM1kO.jpg)

This is my code

```
 for (var i=0 ; i<galleryItems; i++){
            cy.get(galleryPages.elements.addContent).last().click();
            cy.get(galleryPages.elements.galleryItems['staggeredGalleryImage']).click();
            cy.get(galleryPages.elements.galleryItems['thumbnailImage']).click();
            cy.get(galleryPages.elements.galleryItems['addThumbnailImage']).click();
            cy.wait(1000);
            cy.get(galleryPages.elements.galleryItems['txtSearch']).type(galleryObj['Thumbnail Image'][i])
            cy.get(".media-list-grid div[data-element='media-grid-item-0']").click();
            cy.get("umb-button[button-style='success'][label-key='buttons_select'][type='button']").click();
            cy.get(galleryPages.elements.galleryItems['txtLightboxTitle']).type(galleryObj["Lightbox Title"][i])
            cy.wait(1000);
            cy.log("DEBUG " + galleryObj["Lightbox Text"][i])
            cy.get(galleryPages.elements.galleryItems['txtLightboxText'])
            .should('be.visible')
            .then(() => {
            cy.get(galleryPages.elements.galleryItems['txtLightboxText']).then($iframe => {
            cy.wrap($iframe)
              .its('0.contentDocument.body')
              .should('be.visible')
              .then($body => {
                cy.wrap($body).clear().type(galleryObj["Lightbox Text"][i]);
              });
          });
        });

        }
```

but when I use a specific index, I was able to successfully type a value

```
cy.wrap($body).clear().type(galleryObj["Lightbox Text"][1])
```

I want to successfully type a value using an index

Answer (score 4):

The `undefined` value is `galleryObj["Lightbox Text"][i]`.

Presuming you have valid data in `galleryObj`, then the problem is going to be that `i` is above the bounds of the `galleryObj["Lightbox Text"]` array. Check with `console.log('Current  index is: ', i)` just before the fail point.

This happens a lot with for-loops because Cypress commands are asynchronous but the for-loop is not.

To handle it, add an assertion `cy.get(...).should(...)` after each action - after `.click()` and `.type()` - where the page will change because of the action. This slows down the for-loop to make sure you have a valid index value for each step.

I can give you a rough refactor to make the code more readable, showing where to put the assertions to make it work. I include command `.each((imageName, index) =>` to make sure the index does not overrun.

```js
const elements = galleryPages.elements

// selectors
const {
  staggeredGalleryImage, 
  thumbnailImage, 
  addThumbnailImage,
  txtSearch,
  txtLightboxTitle,
} = elements.galleryItems

// aggregate commands
Cypress.Commands.add('addThumbnail', () => {
  cy.get(elements.addContent).last().click();
  cy.get(staggeredGalleryImage).click();
  cy.get(thumbnailImage).click();
  cy.get(addThumbnailImage).click();
  cy.get(...).should(...)        // assertion here to wait for add thumbnail result
})

cy.wrap(galleryObj['Thumbnail Image']).each((imageName, index) => {

  cy.addThumbnail()  

  cy.get(txtSearch).type(imageName)
  cy.get(...).should(...)            // assertion here to wait for search result

  cy.get(txtLightboxTitle).type(galleryObj["Lightbox Title"][index])

  ... and so on
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to type a value even though I didn't add an assertion. I've used each(($iframe, index), but the problem is it always has an index of 0 in every iteration

```
for (var i = 0; i < galleryItems; i++) {
         
            cy.get(galleryPages.elements.galleryItems['txtLightboxText'])
              .should('be.visible')
              .each(($iframe, index) => {
                cy.wrap($iframe)
                  .eq(index)
                  .its('0.contentDocument.body')
                  .should('be.visible')
                  .then($body => {
                    cy.wrap($body).should("be.visible").wait(500);
                    console.log('Current index is: ', index);
                    cy.wrap($body).clear().should("be.visible").type(galleryObj["Lightbox Text"][index]);
                  });
              });
          }
```